# How can I replace hashtag in url?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my angular 1.3 app I have to parse an external url that looks like this:

```
https://127.0.0.1:3000/myState#id_token=someid&access_token=blaat
```

I use the ui-router and have defined a state called myState which has a controller mycontroller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mymodule')
        .controller('mycontroller', contrl)
        .config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }]);


    function contrl($location) {
        if ($location.search().hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
        var token = $location.search()['access_token'];
        }
    }
})();
```

The state looks something like this:

```
.state('myState', {
            url: '/myState',
            controller: 'myController'
        });
```

I am trying to get the access_token from the querystring but the controller does not even get fired. If I replace the # for a ? then the controller will get fired. How can I run the controller and get my access_token ? How can I parse this url?

Comment: A hash is for a location on the page, defined by an ID. A query string, for GET operations is prefixed by a `?`. You should use a query string to get the access token and use $_GET ['access_token'] to retrieve it in the PHP. Alternatively, if you do need to do it client side, you can use JS to split the URL at `&`, and then `=`.

Comment: what is generating this URL? it's definitely malformed.

Comment: At Claeis I was thinking the same , is there a standard specification which says it is malformed?